# Giving a className to a custom React component not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have some component that uses another component. I want the outer component to provide the position CSS to the inner one, so I try to do the following:

```
import OptionsMenu from './OptionsMenu'
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  optionsPosition: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0
  }
});


class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card>
        ...
        <OptionsMenu className={classes.optionsPosition}/>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Modal);
```

The strange thing is that when I wrap `OptionsMenu` in a div, the `className` works

```
<Card>
  ...
  <div className={classes.optionsPosition}>
    <OptionsMenu />
  </div>
</Card>
```

But I want to avoid the unnecessary `div` and understand why does `OptionsMenu` ignores the styling?

Answer (score 4):

When typing `<OptionsMenu className={classes.optionsPosition}/>` you are just declaring that you send to `OptionsMenu` component a prop named `className` that holds the value `classes.optionsPosition`.

In `OptionsMenu` component you can use this prop and apply it as a className on a html DOM element (div/span etc).

Or, in `Card` component you can wrap children (`OptionsMenu`) in a div with the relevant className.

Comment: And how do you deal with a more complex `className` object to apply it on a component and its different subelements?